# Laravel login not working with documents more tha 10 chars

Tags: laravel

Before anything, thank you for your help
I've been having a problem for days with Laravel login. My only credential to login users is their document (it's quite a small system) but, recently, I'm starting to have trouble when logging in with documents larger than 10 chars. Whenever I try to log in with a document like that, it sends me back to the login view with no errors, it just doesn't let me log in.
I'm using the `Auth::loginUsingId($request->document)` (I already checked that the user had `$primaryKey = 'document'`)
I tried to refresh all migrations, show the output of every single line in the login method, but everything seems to be fine, the `Auth::loginUsingId()` returns the corresponding `User` instance but it's just not redirecting to the right view. I really hope you can help me with this one
Here is the code of my login method in the AdminController.php

```
public function login(Request $request) {

    // validacion
    $rules = [
        'document' => 'required|numeric|exists:users,document'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect()
            ->route('admin.login')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    // login
    $document = $request->document;


    if(Auth::loginUsingId($document)){
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }else{
        return redirect()
            ->route('admin.login')
            ->with('status', 'Login Failed');
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show your controller where you are trying to redirect

Comment: I edited the question to include the code of the method where all the deal happens